# AWS Lambda warm functions resending code, how do I stop it?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So my code executes multiple times, almost like it goes back in the code and reexecutes it somehow...

This code gets executed onIntent

```
@Override
public void onIntent(SpeechletRequestEnvelope<IntentRequest> requestEnvelope, Intent intent, String name) {
    IntentRequest request = requestEnvelope.getRequest();
    switch (request.getDialogState()) {
        case STARTED:
            this.speechletResponse = Response.getDialogueResponse(intent, true);
            break;
        case IN_PROGRESS:
            this.speechletResponse = Response.getDialogueResponse(intent, false);
            break;
        case COMPLETED:
            String numberString = intent.getSlot(SlotTitle.ID).getValue();
            if (!NumberUtils.isCreatable(numberString)) {
                this.speechletResponse = Response.ERROR;
                break;
            }

            Member member = Info.GUILD.getMemberById(numberString);
            User sender = UserDB.getUser(member);

            Future<Ticket> commissionTicket = new CommissionTicket(sender).create();
            try {
                commissionTicket.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SpeechletResponse resp = Response.NEW_TICKED_CREATED;
            resp.setNullableShouldEndSession(true);

            this.speechletResponse = resp;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the Ticket#create method that gets run multiple times on the same block

```
public Future<Ticket> create() {
    GuildController guildController = Info.GUILD.getController();
    RequestFuture<Channel> channelRequestFuture = guildController.createTextChannel(ticketType.name().toLowerCase() + "-" + creator.getName() + "-" + id.value()).submit();
    try {
        Channel channel = channelRequestFuture.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        ChannelManager channelManager = channel.getManager();
        GuildManager guildManager = channelManager.getGuild().getManager();
        List<Member> members = guildManager.getGuild().getMembers();
        List<Member> admins = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Member member : members) {
            for (Role role : member.getRoles()) {
                if (!role.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(Info.ADMIN_STRING)) continue;
                admins.add(member);
            }
        }

        for (Member member : members) {
            if (member.equals(creator.getMember())) continue;
            channel.createPermissionOverride(member).setDeny(Permission.MESSAGE_READ).queue();
        }


        for (Member admin : admins) {
            if (admin.equals(creator.getMember())) continue;
            channel.createPermissionOverride(admin).setAllow(Permission.MESSAGE_READ).queue();
        }


        BotMessage botMessage = new BotMessage();
        botMessage
                .setTitle("New Ticket! User: " + creator.getName())
                .setColour(Color.CYAN)
                .setDescription("Please enter your full request here! \n" +
                        "Make sure to let us know whether you are looking for a quote/timeframe,\n" +
                        "or have a budget in mind, and we will work around you!\n\n" +
                        "A sales representative will be with you as soon as possible!")
                .send((TextChannel) channel);


        this.textChannel = (TextChannel) channel;

        TicketDB.addTicket(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!userIsInTicket(creator)) users.add(creator);
    Future<Ticket> future = ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(this);
    return future;

}
```

So, when the Ticket#create code gets ran, it creates a new text channel, unique, and sends a message to that channel.
This is all fine, however then after the channel is created, I call the lambda function again, so it is 'warm', and it creates a new unique text channel as expected, BUT it also sends that message in the channel that was created previously another two times for some unknown reason. If I could get help as to why that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

https://gyazo.com/2432b101a051ce2dc6521e939d8a8690

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the core of your problem is, that some variables (channel) live outside of your handler function.

AWS Lambda is just a Docker container. The container is rebooted sometimes... but generally once it is spun up and initialized, the only thing that happens when you invoke your "warm" lambda is that your handler function is called (by some external AWS thingy) inside your existing and running container...

Hence, anything that lives outside of your handler function and is called only when the code is initialized for the first time and will retain it's initial value in subsequent calls.

Try this out (Python example):

```
from datetime import datetime

now = str(datetime.now())

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return now
```

This snippet of code will live in a module called `lambda_function.py`. When you invoke the lambda for the first time, a Docker container with a Python interpreter will be started that will load your `lambda_function` module and call the `lambda_handler()` function.

However, when you invoke the function second time, the module has already been loaded. Thus the `now` variable has already been initialized and has it's previous value. Subsequent calls to the `lambda_handler()` (or "lambda function invocations" if you want) will just pass the same value that was created when the module was initialized for the first time.